# What does the self argument mean in a function call?

Tags: swift

In the below function call `.didSelectRating` what is the `self` argument(?) indicating? What exactly is this?

I've seen this before a few times and don't know how to learn about this syntax because I don't know what to look up. I understand that the `rating` word in the second argument is the argument name but I don't understand how the first word before the comma encapsulates both the name and argument.

What is this called and what is it doing? Is `self` the only word used here or can something else be here?

```
protocol RatingPickerDelegate {
    func preferredRatingSymbol(picker: RatingPicker) -> UIImage?
    func didSelectRating(picker: RatingPicker, rating: Int)
    func didCancel(picker: RatingPicker)
}


 func selectRating(selectedRating: Int) {
        delegate?.didSelectRating(self, rating: selectedRating)
        // Other logic related to selecting a rating
    }
```

Comment: The requirement for argument labels changed from Swift 2 to Swift 3.  I'm guessing this code is Swift 2; see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"self" makes reference to the current object. Passing it as an argument means that the first argument is an object of that class. "self" keyword is the equivalente of "this" in Java , javascript or c, if it helps you to undestand it or to look up for it.

About why the first argument doesnt require the name, swift language was defines like that. Guess it takes it from objectice-c, where you put name for every argument except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

`self` refers to the object that the method was called on. Here, it is used as a way to pass that object into another method.